# Is there a way to create a staggered table in latex?

Tags: tables

I need to make a staggered table, essentially the first row of the table would have 1 cell, the second row would have 2 cells, the third row 3 cells and so on. Is there a way to do this with the tabular? If not what package would I want to use?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's certainly possible to create a staggered table with the `tabular` environment. For instance:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{*{10}{c}}
\hline
1 \\
1 & 2 \\
1 & 2 & 3 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Note that this particular `tabular` environment has only 5 columns (and rows) even though it is set up to have up to 10 columns. Nothing bad happens if you define the environment to have more columns than you end up using.

You haven't told us anything about the desired column properties across different rows. Thus, the example above may not meet your needs should the cell contents need to be aligned/formatted differently on each row.